# why the python file handling not recognizing file name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace a string with another string in a file. I have below program to perform the task.

```
import os
import sys
import traceback
from glob import iglob


def usage():
    print('Usage: python FindAndReplace.py [Old String] [New String] '
          '[File Filters(default:".txt,.xml")] [Directory To Check(.)]')


def search_replace_string(fileName, old_str, new_str):
    if not(os.path.isfile(fileName) and os.access(fileName, os.W_OK)):
        print("Warning: Skipping..File does not exist or and is not writeable:" + filename)
        return False

    fileupdated = False

    # Read the old file

    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        newlines = []
        for lines in f.readlines():
            if old_str in lines:
                fileupdated = True
            line = lines.replace(old_str, new_str)
            newlines.append(line)

    # Write changes to same file

    if fileupdated:
        print("string Found and Updating File: " + fileName)
        try:
            with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
                for line in newlines:
                    f.write(line)
        except:
            print("Error: Cannot open/access existing file for writing: " + fileName)
    return fileupdated


def main():
    try:
        DEFAULT_PATH = iglob(str('<path_to_file.xml'))
        if len(sys.argv) < 3:
            usage()
            # old/new string required parameters, exit if not supplied
            sys.exit(-1)
        else:
            oldString = sys.argv[1]
            newString = sys.argv[2]

        if len(sys.argv) < 4:
            patterns = ['.xml', '.txt']

        else:
            stringFilter = sys.argv[3]
            patterns = stringFilter.split(',')

        if len(sys.argv) < 5:
            path = DEFAULT_PATH
        else:
            path = sys.argv[4]

        print('[Old String]    :' + oldString)
        print('[New String]    :' + newString)
        print('[File Filters]    :' + ', '.join(patterns))
        print('[Directory To Check]    :' + path)

        if not os.path.exists(path):
            raise Exception("Selected path does not exist: " + path)


        # Walk through directory structure looking for files matching patterns

        matchingFileList = [os.path.join(dp, f) for dp, dn, filenames in os.walk(path) for f in filenames if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in patterns]

        print('Files found matching patterns: ' + str(len(matchingFileList)))
        filecount = 0
        filesReplaced = 0

        for currFile in matchingFileList:
            filecount += 1
            filesReplaced = search_replace_string(currFile, old_str, new_str)
            if filesReplaced:
                filesReplaced += 1

        print("Total Files Searched   :" + str(filecount))
        print("Total Files Replaced/Updated  :" + str(filesReplaced))
    except Exception as err:
        print(traceback.format_exception_only(type(err), err)[0].rstrip())
        sys.exit(-1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I am executing it from a command line I am getting below error:

```
(null): can't open file 'uro.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Below is the command line argument I am giving

```
python uro.py <file_path> <old_str> <new_str>
```

NOTE: I am using xml file.
I wanted to develop a logic that will take file_name, old and new string as a command line argument. In the error one can see that the program is considering the python file a input file. While it should take the path of the file that I give with CMD argument.

What's the mistake here? Please suggest. Thank you

Comment: What is `uro.py` and what has it to do with the rest of the question?

Comment: urp.py contains the code that searches the matched sting and replace it with new one.

Comment: Oh, you mean that `uro.py` contains the code you posted? Well, where is it? Did you write the code yourself in an editor of some sort? Where did you save the file?

Comment: I have written the code in pycharm. But executed it through CMD line with the arguments as shown in my original post.

Comment: Ok, so PyCharm is good. So where did PyCharm store this file? Did you `cd` into this folder before running your command line?

Comment: from the command line, I have CD to the location where my uro.py is present and explicitly gave the XML file path along with it as cmd line argument. I have removed the file path from the original post due to security reasons.

Comment: Perhaps you should try a more simple `Hello World` type of python program before something as complicated as this. Can you list the contents of the directory from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed, there was some path issue. Thank you.